# Raise exception to forbid an update on column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I have the table Photographies with the columns: Name, Author, Created_Date, Updated_date.

I would like to set a condition whereby each time an user tries to update the column Created_Date, the system does not allow him to update it and shows the message below:
"It is not possible to update the column created_date".

I would like to use the sentence `Raise Exception`

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-grant.html) on column?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately use a grant is not an option to solve it. I would like to use "raise exception"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) to do this job.

First create a function to check if the date has been changed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_created_date() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.created_date IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.created_date THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Do not mess up with created_date';
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And attach it to a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update_created_date
BEFORE UPDATE ON photographies
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_created_date();
```

If you try to update it, you get an exception:

```
UPDATE photographies SET created_date = current_date; 
FEHLER:  Do not mess up with created_date
```